# yii : How To Have Ajax Validation On A Part Of The Form Showed With An Ajax Event And A Renderpartial?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it... there is a lot of post whith similar things and despite of that, I can't find any solution.

So I'll try to expose clearly my problem.

I have a form (widget active form) in my main page. on this form the ajax validation works fine.
but, depending of certain option on this form, (for exemple check a radioButton), an additionnal part of the form appears.

```
//start of the form
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'evenement-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
        'clientOptions'=>array('validateOnSubmit'=>true)
                                )); ?>

// some input
...
// my radioButton with my ajax event.
<?php 
echo $form->radioButton($eventForm, 'comboGestionnaireValue', array(
        'value'=>'2',
        'uncheckValue'=>null,
        'onChange'=>CHtml::ajax(array(
             'type'=>'POST',
             'url'=>@Yii::app()->createUrl('admin/UpdateAjaxFormGestionnaire'),
             'data' => array('form'=>serialize($form)),
             'update'=>'#gestionnaireCell')) )); ?>

//the rest of my form.
...
```

So when I check the combobox, it will called the action in my controller.
this is the action :

```
public function actionUpdateAjaxFormGestionnaire()
    { 
        $eventForm = new eventForm;
        $form = $_POST['form'];
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='evenement-form')
        {
                echo $form::validate($eventForm);
                Yii::app()->end();
        }

        $this->renderPartial('_ajaxContentFormGestionnaire', array(
                'form'=>$form,
                ), false, true);        
    }
```

And finnaly my partial view rendered :

```
<?php
$form = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $form);
$form = unserialize($form);

$eventForm = new EventForm;
?>
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($eventForm,"Nom"); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($eventForm,"Nom",array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($eventForm,'Nom'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($eventForm,'Prenom'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($eventForm,'Prenom',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($eventForm,'Prenom'); ?>
</div>

...
```

and I want to have an ajax validation on this rendered part...

In other words :

I guess you understood that I have a form which is growing depending of certains options.

I want that these additionnal fields have a validation to see if they are correctly filled during the user is completing the form

for the first part of my form I don't have any problem. when I click on a required field without filled it and then I click somewhere else, this field becomes red and an error message appear under it. ( same if its a numeric field and some char are lost in it :))

but for the additionnal part (render partial part) I don't have any verification, when I click on a field and then I go away, any POST action (seen in firebug) is send... and then, any ajax verification is done... :(

all my rules are define in my eventForm model.. and I call the ajax validate in my action if there is a Post event...

I think that the problem is that : there are any post action send when I "leave" the field.

please do you have any suggestions? thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

When you write "any" you mean "no" or "none" right?

You have enableAjaxValidation = true, Yii creates a javascript like this:

```
jQuery('#contact-form').yiiactiveform({'validateOnSubmit':true,'validateOnChange':false,'afterValidate':processResult,'attributes':[{'id':'Contact_firstname','inputID':'Contact_firstname','errorID':'Contact_firstname_em_','model':'Contact','name':'Contact[firstname]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group','status':1},{'id':'Contact_lastname','inputID':'Contact_lastname','errorID':'Contact_lastname_em_','model':'Contact','name':'Contact[lastname]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group','status':1},{'id':'Contact_tags','inputID':'Contact_tags','errorID':'Contact_tags_em_','model':'Contact','name':'Contact[tags]','enableAjaxValidation':true,'inputContainer':'div.control-group','status':1}],'errorCss':'error'});
```

As you can see this is a list with all the fields in the form. When you add fields to the form you should also add them to this array to they are also sent over and validated.

I believe you are better of just disabling enableAjaxValidation and just create a small function that will do the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I mean no or none .. sorry I still don't speak english very well :). I'll try your solution and say if it works. Thanks you for your answer.

Comment: and do you know if there is a way to get the javascript created by yii? ( like you did for the contact form? )

Comment: I do not believe there is any way